# Permission Error running through Notepad++

Tags: python, permissions

I have a Python 2.7 program that prints a set of data to a text file at the end.  The program works perfectly if I import the file into the Pythonshell, but if I attempt to run the script directly from Notepad++ using Crl+R (also using Pythonshell), I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\ZeemanLab.py", line 140, in <module>
    with open("Mercury{}at{}A".format(wavelength, B), "w") as f:
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Mercury55at55A'
```

The problem line:

```
with open("Mercury{}at{}A".format(wavelength, B), "w") as f: 
    f.write('A {}nm lamp in a {}A Magnetic field \n'.format(wavelength, B))
```

I am clueless as to what would make this difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding and printing the result of `os.getcwd()` might help you troubleshoot. Perhaps Notepad++ is running the script from a different working directory? Have you tried using an absolute path name like `C:\temp\Mercury{}at{}A`?

Comment: Absolute path was my first thought.  It did eventually work although it the \ need to be doubled.  eg. C:\\Users

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permission of the file, or move it to a directory where it has the right privileges.
Under windows 7 english the way to do it is:

1. Left click on the file
2. Click properties
3. Press Security
4. In "group or user names:", choose your user and click edit.
5. Set the permerssion to read and write.

If you can't, you might have to change to the Adminster user. However the easiest solution is just to move the folder of your project, and run it in your document, desktop or some other folder.

Comment: Doesn't always work. Trust me, Python is the worst language when dealing with Windows file permissions.

Comment: Thats why I just have a folder I put all my projects in, when I am working on windows, and also why I recommended it :)

Comment: Python on Windows could still have been better. I mean, say the file is in another folder, and you can't change the location. Shoving a "Before you begin" note in every end user's face isn't always an option.

I guess there's still always the Python Win32 API. But it's still a little overkill...

Comment: I mostly do server side, so I don't lot about this. But what about packing python with the program, and make a simple batch or exe file that starts python. I think Anki does a bit like this. http://www.ankisrs.net/ Anki is a very good project with one automatic installer

Comment: Well, py2exe lets you embed manifests. But py2exe also can give annoying DLL errors and such. Which is what happened to me. Packing the entire Python language with the program isn't practical. And, embedding Python into a C++ program with Administrator privileges doesn't work(I tried). Argh.

Comment: Sounds like you're more experience with deployment to clients than me. But Java, Python and all other interpreter languages are always a pain to get to work when deployed.

Comment: Not on Linux, or even Windows 90% of the time. But, when UAC is involved, hell gets loose. That's one of the reasons I'm learning C#.

Comment: Of course not on Linux, everything works there when talking about python. Preinstalled etc. Just sad my graphics and network card only half work in Linux.

C# and visual studio is the best. It seriously improves your productivity :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried Pascal and didn't like it much. C# is pretty good. And, what Linux were you using that your graphics card didn't work?

Comment: I tried Ubuntu, PCLinuxOS, and mint. My graphics card works half okay(except I got two screens and it can't extend). In Ubuntu I can see my wireless networks, but can't connect(even through I changed the settings in my router).
In pclinuxos/mint I can't even find my wireless card :'( and I used like a whole day just searching about network issues. No luck :(
With some poking and mintifi(I think) I can find the wireless, but not connect.

Comment: Really annoys me that it is so hard to get drivers to work in Linux